# Xero API pdf attachment received but not displaying

Tags: xero-api

I have set up the attachments API and everything seems to be working.

I am converting the file into base64. It is recieved against the invoice in xero however when i view the pdf it says it cannot load."Failed to load pdf document".

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwztq.jpg)

The same thing happens if i downlaod the document.

I have checked the base64 code in other decoders and it seems to be working fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the http request should contain the raw attachment content, it shouldn't be converted to Base64